# Does using Doctrine mean having to look up the parent (referenced) row object?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, doctrine-orm

Say I have tables like so

- user (id, username);
- user_record(id, user_id, record);

Assume that you already know `user.id`, say it has been provided from elsewhere.  I can issue a *single* SQL command to insert a user record like so:

```
INSERT INTO user_record (user_id, record) values($userId, 'entry');
```

When using Doctrine, however it seems to me like you can't just do this because you can't simply insert a record without looking up the user object first.  So in Doctrine first you set up entities, set up foreign keys relations and then you have to look up the user record first to be able to do something like ..

```php
$record = new UserRecord();

//SQL #1 to find user because we need $user to be an object, not a string
$user = $em->find('User', $userId); 

$record->setUserName($user); //pass user object
$record->setRecord('record');
$em->persist($record);

//SQL #2 -- actual insert
$em->flush($record);
```

So in Doctrine you use up 2 queries when in pure SQL you would use up only one.  Can Doctrine be made to use a single query when `user.id` is known?

Comment: off topic question here ... why is `username` your FK and not your `user`.`id` with something like `user_record`.`user_id`

Comment: short answer:  legacy code...   long answer .. because using `user_record(id, user_id, record)` *will* require looking up `user.id` since it won't be available in the code.  Which will equalize both ways....  but my question will remain.. if I know `id` I still have to use Doctrine to pull that record up

Comment: which site would find this question to be on topic?..

Comment: Doctrine supports the notion of references ($em->getReference('User',$userId) which would allow you to make the association without actually loading the user.  However, it only works with the primary key. I think you will find that trying to establish relations between entities that don't use primary keys will, in general,  be a bit challenging in Doctrine.

Comment: ^ Thanks, that will help.  And I'm working on reworking the tables to use primary key relationships...

Comment: @Cerad, if you post your last comment as answer I can accept